# Highcharts showing points on hovering over the line which are outside the chart area when the chart is zoomed in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I have started working on highcharts recently and for my project I require the following prototype chart where I can zoom in or zoom out. I want to show the y-axis value in tooltip only when the user moves the mouse pointer exactly on the points. But in highcharts if I hover on the line, it shows the y-axis value of the nearest point in the tooltip.
My problem is when I zoom in to see a particular set of points and if I hover on the line, it shows the y-axis value of the points which are outside the chart area.

http://jsfiddle.net/ssaptarshii/hkn8c27n/

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart:{
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
        x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
        x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature (°C)'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '°C'
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
    }]
});
```

});

In the link above, if I zoom in such a way that a part of the graph between **June and September** is outside (above) the chart area and then hover on the line segment between **June and July**, then the y-axis value (shown by the tooltip) for the x-axis value (**July**) becomes visible which is already out of the graph screen. The y-axis value for **July** appears some-where near the title of the graph.

I do not want to show all such y-axis values on tooltip which are outside of the chart area if it is zoomed in and also I want to disable the feature to show the points by hovering on the line.

Comment: Please create a jsFiddle for debugging..

Comment: In your fiddle there are not any cooradinates, could you update your example with correct code which introduce issue?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I updated the question. It is the tooltip value of the points, not the co-ordinate of the points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheilak/ykn77Lmw/)

Added these series options:

```
type: 'scatter',
stickyTracking: false,
lineWidth: 2,
```